# PHP output buffer fails

Tags: php, windows, cmd, system, buffer

Just as a demo, try the following code:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';      
ob_end_flush();
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
passthru("ping -n 8 127.0.0.1");
@ob_flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This is the output:

```
Pinging stackoverflow.com [64.34.119.12] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=56
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=56
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=56
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 64.34.119.12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 29ms, Average = 28ms

Pinging stackoverflow.com [64.34.119.12] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=56
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=56
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=56
Reply from 64.34.119.12: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 64.34.119.12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 26ms, Maximum = 29ms, Average = 27ms
```

It actually does it twice (which is from the "is less than 2" loop). If you test the script, you'll notice that it takes a few seconds to do the first one, then it outputs it all at once. After that (second loop) it goes line by line. My goal is just to have a single output, go line by line and not buffer any output, like the following does except as it happens:

```
<?php
system("ping -n 8 127.0.0.1");
?>
```

Note: This is running on a Windows server with PHP 5.

Comment: I don't see where you're ***starting*** the output buffering...?

Comment: I don't want output buffering at all. The last PHP code block I posted only shows output after the command finished. The same exact thing happens for passthru and system alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what is happening here is your browser is likely buffering.  I think if you look at a packet sniffer, your flushes are probably working.

Just to be sure, call `flush()` as well as `ob_flush()`.

You can never clear out all of the buffers, as PHP is only aware of its own.  The server can buffer, and the clients almost always buffer.

Comment: With both flush() and ob_flush() called directly before OR after (tried before AND after too) the browser still doesn't obey it?

Comment: Nevermind. This works as intended in IE but not Firefox? I am now twice as confused as when I asked the question.

Comment: @mesh Welcome to the world according to Internet Explorer. You'll be excused if you want to jump off a cliff now.

Comment: One last thing, as a hunch: Perhaps mod_deflate has a buffer, but does not buffer for IE because it sucks anyways, thus making IE work in this situation and not FF? I'm disabling compression and testing... result: did not fix anything.

Comment: @rdlowrey, I don't see how buffering a page is typically a problem, and shouldn't really be a strike against IE.  Chrome and others buffer as well, and for good reason.  Mesh, fire up a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, and watch exactly what is being sent to the browser.  Again, what is being sent is all you can control.  The buffer you're seeing is undoubtedly on the client side, which you have no control over.

Comment: @Brad - Packet sniffed... Each line of the ping request is sent with one-second intervals (as it should) but the browser is not displaying it until finished. Is there something I can change with header() to make the media type different and trick the browser?

Comment: @mesh, No, you cannot control the buffer of the browser!  Most browsers display content once they have enough of it, so you could send 1KB of comment tags at the beginning to try to start this process, but that isn't guaranteed to work.  Do this differently... use AJAX.  There is nothing you can do about it.